# How to setup fully TDD Rails API with React frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rspec

I have some background questions, because the more I think about it, the more confused I get.

What I want to make is a very simple reviewsite where people can leave a review/comment with a rating (no signin function). The frontend will have to be in React and it will also need an average rating component.

So far I set up a rails API and in the model I included a title, description and rating. But I'm thinking that it might be better to make a separate model for the ratings?? I'm not sure when it's better to create a separate model.

My second questions is; How would I test a React component using Rspec? Would I need a gem for that?? I don't understand how that even works when the Rspec file is in the Rails API, and you want to test a component inside the React app...

Maybe someone could explain this or send me a good link where I can find this information?? Of course I tried google, but it just left me even more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't build a SPA application just by using React. React is not a framework it's a library so you have to include React into a framework like AngularJS. Then, you can't test React or AngularJS with Rspec because Rspec is not meant for UI testing. You should use something like Protractor. Also, I recommend you look at Grape API to build the service layer of your application. Finally you should add a separate model for ratings if you build the application on a RDBMS because there could number of ratings. Otherwise for something like mongodb you can embed the ratings into the post table.